# Maximum Possible Sum of Sequence $F_n = F_{n-1} \% F_{n-2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, modular-arithmetic

We define a sequence $F_n$ as follows:

$F_{n} = F_{n - 1} \% F_{n - 2}, \forall n \geq 3$, where $\%$ is the modulo operator

We are given an integer $c \geq 0$, and asked to choose values $a, b$ such that $c \geq a \geq b$ and $F_1 = a, F_2 = b$. Our goal is to choose $a, b$ that maximize $S_c = \sum_{n = 3}^{\infty}{F_n}$. Is it possible to (without brute force) find a method that enables us to pick the values of $a$ and $b$ that maximize $S_c$, given a value $c$?

For example, given $c = 10$, if we pick $a = 9, b = 7$, our sequence becomes:
  $F_1 = 9, F_2 = 7, F_3 = 2, F_4 = 1, F_5 = 0, F_n = 0,  \forall n \geq 6$. This means our sum is $2 + 1 + 0 + 0 ... = 3$.

I did some basic case work, and found that the maximum value for $S_{10}$ is $6$, by picking $a = 10, b = 6$. After writing a program to calculate values, I found the maximum value of $S_{100}$ to be $93$, by choosing $a = 97, b = 60$. However, I can't think of a way to generalize these findings.

Any help/observations would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: One small observation: The procdure to generate the sequence $F_n$ is very similar to the euclidean algorithm, which has its worst running time if you calculate the gcd of two consequtive Fibonacci numbers. My guess is that if $c$ is a Fibonacci number, then $a = c$ and setting $b$ to the next-smallest Fibonacic number will yield the biggest value. Can you confirm this with your program?

Comment: Interesting observation @Dominik. Just ran a couple of values, and that's confirmed - for example, setting $c = 89$ yielded $a = 89, b = 55$, and $c = 144$ yielded $a = 144, b = 89$.

Comment: Another observation: $60 = 55 + 5$ and $97 = 89 + 8$ . It could be useful to write the maximizing numbers as sums of Fibonacci numbers to get a nice recursion.

Comment: Do values between fibonacci numbers yield the same results?